# Why is Google Assistant able to take the screenshots even if FLAG_SECURE is set?

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk

I have some user-sensitive information in my app and I want to disable screenshots in it via standard system shortcuts or Google Assistant. WindowManager's  FLAG_SECURE, which I use, doesn't disable screenshots via Google Assistant on some devices. Is it a system bug? Is there any workaround for it?

Following the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/assistant#excluding_views), I've set FLAG_SECURE for my activity window. It does not work on all the devices.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

On Google Pixel 2 device (Android 9.0) it works fine. Screenshots are disabled. Google assistant returns black image as a screenshot.
On Samsung A6 device (Android 9.0) i cannot take a screenshot via system shortcuts, but Google Assistant is still able to take a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known security issues. Seems it is already fixed with the latest security patch on Pixel devices, but not on Samsung devices.